# I got my dependency version as Tag instead of 1.0 in jitpack..?

Tags: java, android

I launched a dependency in jitpack and I got the release version as Tag instead of 1.0.Why..?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iugd4.png)

```
dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.Naveen-R-M:connectioncheck:Tag'
    }
```

Comment: Because you need to create a release first and later Tag will be replaced by the release name

Comment: I have already created a release..

Comment: maybe it's a bug if you are sure you can try replacing Tag with 1.0 if you are sure... it will work